# Fixing this CIDR range for AWS VPC

Tags: c#, amazon-vpc, subnet, cidr, private-subnet

I am using CDK with C# to create a VPC and subnets in `us-east-1`.

```
    var newVpc = new Vpc(this, "myVPC", new VpcProps
    {
        MaxAzs = 3,
        IpAddresses = IpAddresses.Cidr("192.168.1.0/16"),
        EnableDnsHostnames = true,
        EnableDnsSupport = true,
    });
```

Here are the two private subnets I am attempting to create.

```
   var pvtSub1 = new Subnet(this, "pvt-sub1", new SubnetProps
   {
       VpcId = myVpc.VpcId,
       AvailabilityZone = "us-east-1a",
       CidrBlock = "192.168.1.0/28",
       MapPublicIpOnLaunch =false
   });

   var pvtSub2 = new Subnet(this, "pvt-sub2", new SubnetProps
   {
       VpcId = myVpc.VpcId,
       AvailabilityZone = "us-east-1b",
       CidrBlock = "192.168.1.16/28",
       MapPublicIpOnLaunch = false
   });
```

These are failing with error message:

> Resource handler returned message: "The CIDR '192.168.1.0/28' is
> invalid
> Resource handler returned message: "The CIDR
> '192.168.1.16/28' is invalid

Why would these be invalid? When I checked [here](https://www.exampointers.com/ipv4/192.168.1.0/28/) the subnets 0 and 1 seem to be reflecting my specifications in CDK. So, what am I missing?

Comment: What is the VPC's CIDR range that was created in which you are adding the Subnets?

Comment: @Halod VPC CIDR is 192.168.1.1/16

Comment: @Halod I also corrected the VPC CIDR above to be  192.168.1.0/16 and I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you try to create VPC with CIDR 192.168.0.0/16 and then subnets?

Comment: Is 192.168.1.0 not correct?

Comment: The correct subnet mapping for a /16 is to only mention first 2 octets where as for a /24 (or anything above /16) you can mention values in third octet too.

With AWS Webconsole mentioning `192.168.1.0/16` will lead to an error of "Must be a valid IPv4 CIDR." where as with AWS CLI, it gets converted to `192.168.0.0/16` and applied. I am assuming that the CDK seems to not proceeding with that. CLI output

`aws ec2 create-vpc --cidr-block '192.168.1.0/16' --query 'Vpc.CidrBlock'`

gives below: 
`192.168.0.0/16`

Comment: I am able to create a VPC with CIDR range 192.168.0.0/16 and subnets as 192.168.0.0/28 and 192.168.0.16/28 using the console. Then I deleted the VPC and related subnets using the console and tried to create it using CDK : VPC with CIDR range 192.168.0.0/16 and subnets as 192.168.0.0/28 and 192.168.0.16/28. This gives an error saying: `The CIDR '192.168.0.0/18' conflicts with another subnet`. Why would this conflict not be seen in the console?

Comment: @Halod beat me :) - the error may be misleading; but the reason is that CDK created `192.168.0.0/16` and therefore `192.168.1.0/28` is invalid *not* because it is invalid CIDR; but because it doesn't belong to VPC

Comment: @Felix: As per what Halod mentioned I created VPC with CIDR `192.168.0.0/16` and subnets `192.168.0.0/28` and `192.168.0.16/28`. This gets me the error: `"The CIDR `192.168.0.0/18` conflicts with another subnet. How do I find what VPC this subnet is in? I don't see any other VPC using the 192.168 range in my region. Also I don't know where `192.168.0.0/18` came from. I specified `192.168.0.0/16` for the VPC CIDR.

Comment: Not 100% sure on this but the error that you are getting seems to be related to https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6683 . Thats on CDK it seems

Comment: so its weird then. I created a completely new range that I have never used before and I am getting the same issue. I replace 192 with 173 from the ranges above to get this error: ` "The CIDR '173.168.0.0/18' conflicts with another subnet`. I've never used 173 ever. Guess deleting the stack in CDK and CloudFormation is what I can try next.

Comment: what is surprising? you have 192.168.0.0/`28` and .0.16/`28`, right? Of course 192.168.0.0/`18` conflicts with *both* of them! It is overlapping! If it surprises you, you need to catch up on CIDR. or are you saying that you are *not* creating this /18 subnet - and it is a mystery how it came about? Maybe you should create another question.

Comment: @Felix yes, I'm not creating the /18 subnet. It seems liek cdk is doing that automatically. I used `SubnetConfiguration` property in the vpc instead of the `Subnet` construct above and getting further that way without the overlapping /18 subnet. I gather that cdk creates the `vpc` in a way that wont allow updates if the subnet cidr didn't change. Alternatively one has to drop he entire `vpc` first before recreating it again.